# Android Studio Cannot find JAR 'org.eclipse.jgit-4.5.3.201708160445-r.jar'

Tags: java, android

this error show when I open project on android studio, I already search of solution but not solve the error:

```
Cannot find JAR 'org.eclipse.jgit-4.5.3.201708160445-r.jar' required by module 'gradle-version-control' using classpath or distribution directory 'C:\Users\***\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.4-all\9br9xq1tocpiv8o6njlyu5op1\gradle-4.4'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this error too and mistakenly found the answer. If you follow your path in the error you will find the source of the problem.

As it turns out `Android Studio` is supposed to update `Gradle` at the same time but it seems for both of us it didn't.

You will need to:

1. Find the latest verison and download the "complete" `Gradle` zip.
2. Extract to the location of your error.
3. Delete the files in there from previous download.
4. Launch Android Studio, then proceed to File -> Project Structure -> Project and update the Gradle version number.